# MODULE_NOT_FOUND error despite intellisense and tsc compiling working between 2 folders

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, modulenotfounderror

I have a folder with one library, config, and another library, js_query.

```
Heirarchy (dist is generated from tsc) 

root
  js_query
    src/index.ts
    dist/src/index.js
    dist/src/index.d.ts
  config
    src/index.ts
    dist/src/index.js
    dist/src/index.d.ts
```

config tsconfig.json

```
{
  "include": ["*", "src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */

    /* Projects */    
    "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */    
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */    
    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    "outDir": "dist",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */    
    /* Interop Constraints */    
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  }    
}
```

js_query tsconfig.json

```
{
  "include": ["*", "src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"],
  "references": [{"path": "../config"}],  
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */

    /* Projects */    
    "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */    
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */    
    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    "outDir": "dist",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */    
    /* Interop Constraints */    
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  }    
}
```

In the compiled .js code I can see that there is no kind of path change being made to get the file pointed at the dist/src/index.js target and I think that may be the problem, I'm just not sure how to get these things playing together.

Oh, and here is the code for index.ts in js_query where I'm including config library.  Running this generates module not found error.

```
import Database from 'better-sqlite3';
import { config, loadConfig } from '../../config/src';
loadConfig('./config/root.json');
console.log(config);
```

Comment: A lot of what's in here is me troubleshooting, so if you see things I should cut out let me know.

Comment: As far as I can tell you need to include the output file not the source file so it would be `../../config/dist`. If you compile using `tsc --build tsconfig.json` it should transpile the reference packages first

Comment: It won't let me include the output file like that in the .ts because the .ts file is not in the same directory as the .js

When it transpiles it should know to make the .js reference a folder up but it's just not doing it.  

And I can't understand this when it has all the information it should need to have to know to do that stored in these tsconfig.json files.  I assume this is a bug of some sort.

Comment: I found that I can get it to work if I use absolute path in the import, even if not using the .js file as the target

This is a bit annoying because I use vscode in windows and linux and the paths aren't going to be the same between the 2. 

I tried the relative path as ../config and ..\\config and neither option worked.  I also tried the same version of that but targetting the .js file, which intellisense detects as fine, and tsc works with as well, but node itself seems not to be able to resolve.  Maybe a bug in node 19.7 and how it evaluates ../ paths